# Why Sendgrid API works in localhost but in server need another API

Tags: go, sendgrid

Today I faced with Sendgrid problem. I get SendGrid API and write message

```
from := mail.NewEmail(message.Fullname, "example@gmail.com")
    subject := "Новая заявка в Litro.kz"
    to := mail.NewEmail(message.Fullname, "example@gmail.com")
    plainTextContent := "ФИО: "+ message.Fullname + "\n Email:  " +message.Email + "\n Номер телефона: "+ message.Phone +"\n Сообщение: "+message.Text
    htmlContent := "ФИО: "+ message.Fullname + "<br> Email:  " +message.Email + "<br> Номер телефона: "+ message.Phone +"<br> Сообщение: "+message.Text
    messages := mail.NewSingleEmail(from, subject, to, plainTextContent, htmlContent)

    client := sendgrid.NewSendClient(os.Getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY"))
    response, err := client.Send(messages)

    if err != nil || response.StatusCode!=202 {
        log.Println(err)
        fmt.Println(response)
        return u.Message(false,"Error")
    }else{
        fmt.Println(response.Body)
        fmt.Print(response.StatusCode)
    }
```

It is part of my code. When I run this code in localhost everything is ok, but after i downloaded to server. I have problem like

```
&{401 {“errors”:[{“message”:“Permission denied, wrong credentials”,“field”:null,“help”:null}]} map[Access-Control-Allow-Headers:[Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl] Access-Control-Allow-Methods:[POST] Access-Control-Allow-Origin:[https://sendgrid.api-docs.io] Access-Control-Max-Age:[600] Connection:[keep-alive] Content-Length:[88] Content-Type:[application/json] Date:[Mon, 04 Nov 2019 08:33:17 GMT] Server:[nginx] X-No-Cors-Reason:[https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html]]}
```

Please, help to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting the `SENDGRID_API_KEY` environment variable correctly on the server?

Comment: of course) Before asking I did everything I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SendGrid's API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/api-reference/) requires an authorization header.  If you are using a [client library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java) a [SENDGRID_API_KEY](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys) was probably set up for testing.

In new server, make sure an environment variable is set with a `SENDGRID_API_KEY`.

For Java, copy the sample environment file to a new file

```
cp .env_sample .env
```

Edit the new .env to add your API key, then Source the .env file to set rhe variable in the current session

```
source .env
```

Further information on the API set can be found in the [client library documentation](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java#setup-environment-variables).